# Why does data that exists before returning become undefined after return? (javascript function)

Tags: javascript

My recursive function works perfectly internally.
But when called, it doesn't.

```
function recursiveDataCreator(data, _level, _resultData){
    let level = typeof _level == "undefined" ? 0 : _level;
    let resultData = typeof _resultData == "undefined" ? [] : _resultData;
    let setResultFunc = function(entry, upperKey, target){
        if(upperKey == null || typeof upperKey == "undefined"){
            target.push(entry);
        }else{
            target.forEach((it)=>{
                if(it.key == upperKey){
                    if(typeof it.children == "undefined"){
                        it.children = [];
                    }
                    it.children.push(entry);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    let lvData = data.filter((it)=>it.level==level);
    let nextData = data.filter((it)=>it.level!=level);
    lvData.forEach((it)=>{
        let entry = {
            key: it.key
            , upperKey: it.upperKey
            , title: it.title
            , data: it.data
        };
        setResultFunc(entry, it.upperKey, resultData);
    });
    if(nextData.length == 0){
        console.log("before return");
        console.log(resultData);
        return resultData;
    }else{
        recursiveDataCreator(nextData, (level+1), resultData);
    }
}
```

This case is good. this is sample data.

```
const initData1 = [
    { "level": 0, "key": "A100000", "upperKey": null, "title": "root_1", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 0, "key": "A200000", "upperKey": null, "title": "root_2", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 0, "key": "A300000", "upperKey": null, "title": "root_3", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 0, "key": "A400000", "upperKey": null, "title": "root_4", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 0, "key": "A500000", "upperKey": null, "title": "root_5", data: "dummy" }
];
let makedData1 = recursiveDataCreator(initData1);
console.log("after return");
console.log(makedData1);
```

This is sample data result.

```
before return
VM35:32 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
VM35:48 after return
VM35:49 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Another case is not good. this is another sample data.

```
const initData2 = [
    { "level": 0, "key": "A100000", "upperKey": null, "title": "root_1", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 1, "key": "A101000", "upperKey": "A100000", "title": "root_1_1", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 1, "key": "A102000", "upperKey": "A100000", "title": "root_1_2", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 0, "key": "A200000", "upperKey": null, "title": "root_2", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 1, "key": "A201000", "upperKey": "A200000", "title": "root_2_1", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 2, "key": "A201010", "upperKey": "A201000", "title": "root_2_1_1", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 1, "key": "A202000", "upperKey": "A200000", "title": "root_2_2", data: "dummy" }
];
let makedData2 = recursiveDataCreator(initData2);
console.log("after return");
console.log(makedData2);
```

This is another sample data result.

```
before return
VM35:32 (2) [{…}, {…}]
VM35:74 after return
VM35:75 undefined
```

Why does data that exists before returning become undefined after return?

Comment: Have you tried tracing/logging the recursive calls and returns? Because you don't have `return` under the `else` for the recursive tree so the return value is most likely stopped only at the deepest call in the tree.

Comment: Therefore, that function doesn't return anything that makes it `undefined` when you try to cast the value to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have `return` under the else for the recursive tree so the return value is most likely stopped only at the deepest call in the tree. Therefore, that function doesn't return anything that makes it `undefined` when you try to cast the value to the variable.

```js
let dataInRecursive;

function recursiveDataCreator(data, _level, _resultData){
    let level = typeof _level == "undefined" ? 0 : _level;
    let resultData = typeof _resultData == "undefined" ? [] : _resultData;
    let setResultFunc = function(entry, upperKey, target){
        if(upperKey == null || typeof upperKey == "undefined"){
            target.push(entry);
        }else{
            target.forEach((it)=>{
                if(it.key == upperKey){
                    if(typeof it.children == "undefined"){
                        it.children = [];
                    }
                    it.children.push(entry);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    let lvData = data.filter((it)=>it.level==level);
    let nextData = data.filter((it)=>it.level!=level);
    lvData.forEach((it)=>{
        let entry = {
            key: it.key
            , upperKey: it.upperKey
            , title: it.title
            , data: it.data
        };
        setResultFunc(entry, it.upperKey, resultData);
    });
    if(nextData.length == 0){
        console.log("before return");
        console.log(resultData);
        dataInRecursive = resultData;
        return resultData;
    }else{
        return recursiveDataCreator(nextData, (level+1), resultData);
    }
}

const initData2 = [
    { "level": 0, "key": "A100000", "upperKey": null, "title": "root_1", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 1, "key": "A101000", "upperKey": "A100000", "title": "root_1_1", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 1, "key": "A102000", "upperKey": "A100000", "title": "root_1_2", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 0, "key": "A200000", "upperKey": null, "title": "root_2", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 1, "key": "A201000", "upperKey": "A200000", "title": "root_2_1", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 2, "key": "A201010", "upperKey": "A201000", "title": "root_2_1_1", data: "dummy" },
    { "level": 1, "key": "A202000", "upperKey": "A200000", "title": "root_2_2", data: "dummy" }
];
let makedData2 = recursiveDataCreator(initData2);
console.log("after return");
console.log(makedData2);

// Check if the returned data same or not.
console.log(makedData2 === dataInRecursive);
```